# TCPDF - use proportional numbers in output

Tags: php, tcpdf, glyph

In my PDF I'm trying to output numbers. No problem with that.
The font I'm using is [Vollkorn](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Vollkorn).

The numbers displayed although aren't what I'm looking for.
They look like this:

[image]

Using the font in Adobe Illustrator, when I switch the font to uppercase, a new variant of numbers is shown:

[image]

I would like the use the second set in my PDF output.

Opening the font in FontForge I can see those glyphs but none of them has an Unicode value assigned to it.

Is there some way to use theese number characters in TCPDF? My text is outputed via `MultiCell();`

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530894/231316

Comment: So I ended up replacing the original number glyphs with the ones I need using FontForge. Then I replaced my font with the newly generated one. Works like a charm. Thanks